# Django-channels - messages based on url

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm very new to `django-channels` so this is probably a very simple question.

On our website, there is a permanent button "Messages" in the header. I want user to be notified about new message immediately. So I use channels for this purpose. If there is a new message created, I send a number of not readed conversations through `channels` to client:

```
class Message(..):
    def save(...):
        notify_recipient(self)

    def notify_recipient(self):
        Group('%s' % self.recipient).send({
            "text": json.dumps({
                "message":{"text":truncatechars(self.text,100)},
                "unreaded_conversations":Conversation.objects.get_unreaded_conversations(self.recipient).count(),
            }),
        })
```

And in `base.html`:

```
            const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
            webSocketBridge.connect('/notifications/');
            webSocketBridge.listen(function (action, stream) {
                console.log(action, stream);
                var conversations_sidebar = $('#id_conversations_sidebar');
                var messages_list = $('#messagesList');
                if (action.unreaded_conversations) {
                    $('#id_unreaded_conversations_count').text(action.unreaded_conversations);
                }
```

On the other hand, there is a page `/chat/detail/<username>/` where users chat with each other. This chat should be live so I need to recieve messages through channels.

For now, I've added rendered message to the `notify_recipient` method but the problem is that it has to render the message allways, even when user is not on this `/chat/detail/<username>/` url which is not efficient.

Do you know how to recieve rendered messages only when user is in the current chat?

**routing.py**

```
@channel_session_user
def message_handler(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})


@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message,):

    Group("%s" % message.user).add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})


channel_routing = [

    route("websocket.receive", message_handler),  # we register our message handler
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect)  # we register our message handler
]
```